# Angular 4 component two way binding issue

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an array:

```
const a = [apple,ball,cat]
```

I'm passing this to two components:

```
<app-header [appData]="data"  ></app-header>

<list-todo [appData]="data" [getData]="getData" [setData]="setData" ></list-todo>
```

In the `appHeader` component,

```
export class appHeader  {
  @Input('appData') data : any

  clear(){
    this.data = []
  }
}
```

performing the `clear()` function is not affecting the array in the `listTodo` component. Is there any way to solve that issue?

I also checked two way binding with attributes but nothing worked anymore!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By doing `this.data = []`, you're not emptying your array, but replacing it with a *new instance*. Your parent component and the other child component are still referring to the original instance, which results in the behavior you describe.

One solution is to empty the original array instead of replacing it:

```
clear() {
    this.data.length = 0;
}
```

In doing so, all components will keep referring to the same array instance, and its state will be correctly reflected.

Comment: Thanks Bro it's Working fine !!

Answer (score 7):

`Input` binding sends data to child component in unidirectional way, so when we modify child component data it doesn't flow up. Since you're assigning new blank array to `this.appData` in child component(it doesn't flow up). In this case you could consider changing your `appData` property binding to be two way binding. So that anything updates in child component will update the relative property in parent component, but yes it doesn't happen magically. You have to update the data manually ;)

To make the same thing working, you have to emit `changed` copy of object to parent `component` via `Output` binding like `[(appData)]="data"` (it uses EventEmitter to emit data to parent compoent).

**AppComponent Template**

```
 <app-header [appData]="data"  ></app-header>
<list-todo [(appData)]="data"></list-todo>
```

**ListTodoComponent**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'list-todo',
  template: `
     <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let item of appData">{{item}}</li>
     </ul>
     <button (click)="clear()">Clear</button>
  `
})
export class ListTodoComponent { 
  @Input() appData;
  @Output() appDataChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

  clear(){
    this.appData = [];
    //this emit is important to send data back to parent.
    //make sure you should have `Change` prefix to bounded value, like `appData` + `Change` = `appDataChange`, 
    //which ultimately saves few lines of code.
    this.appDataChange.emit(this.appData); 
  }
}
```

[**Demo Here**](https://plnkr.co/edit/tSB7p4UTELqoK3F5w8KZ?p=preview)

Comment: Your comment here saved me some headache, I **cannot believe** that the name must be the same as the property and end with `Change` - no other name is allowed!  Renaming this to `appDataChanged` (with a 'd' on the end) makes it not return a value to the parent!